# Time dependency on autosys

Tags: unix, job-scheduling, autosys

Hi I have below JIL for Autosys. I want to run this job only on Saturday after the success of job `axm_c_hk_purge_files_axiom`. I don't want to make this job dependent on time. but if i don't mention `start_times:` this gives error. I don't want to mention any time here. this gives error. How can I remove time dependency from this job.If i remove `start_times` tag or put it null in both the cases it gives error

```
insert_job: axm_c_hk_restart_appsvr job_type: CMD
box_name: axm_b_usreg_wkly_jobs
command: /apps/axiom_app/axiom7/autosys_start_axiom_srvr.ksh
machine: rrany-live.barcapint.com
owner: regnyprd
permission:
date_conditions: 1
days_of_week: sa
start_times: "20:15"
condition: s(axm_c_hk_purge_files_axiom)
description: "Command Job to stop AXIOM 7.8 application server"
std_out_file: /tmp/axm_c_hk_restart_appsvr.out
std_err_file: /tmp/axm_c_hk_restart_appsvr.err
max_run_alarm: 15
alarm_if_fail: 1
profile: /home/regnyprd/.bourne.profile.r11.3
timezone: NewYork
```

Could you please help me on the same.

Comment: Yes..thanks  Piyush

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep this job under a box.
Set start condition of the of the box as saturday and 00:01 hours and term_run_time as 24hrs.

Change hours and terminate times as per need.

For the job donot define any start time only success of the previous job.

During Saturday if the predecessor job is success  the job would trigger and upon success the box will get completed.

Otherwise the box would get terminated.

While on other days this job would not run even if the predecessor job changes it's status.

Please Map the box start time and predecessor job accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

If you specify days_of_week you need to have start_time. You can get around by using run_calendar. If you do use run_calendar you might want to add a lookback for your condition so it will not trigger right at midnight, but after the job completes.